# How to split a string into only positive and negative integers?

Tags: java, string, split

I'm writing a program to do different calculations with vector functions, but the program I have as of now delimits the negative digits. I've tried using different delimiters but I can't seem to get the right one.

Does anyone know how to keep the positive and negative digits when splitting a string? Also, is there a way to keep any decimal values? .45 would return 45 and .29 would return 29

This is the code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

String twoVectors = "a=<-1,2,-3> b=<4,-5,6>"; // vector and a and b

String[] tokens = twoVectors.split("\\D");

for (String s : tokens)
    if (!s.equals(""))
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

When I run the program I get [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] instead of [-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6]. All the functions I have worked perfectly fine but dont work when using negative values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: with regex, you could easily use `-?\d`

Comment: I wouldn't rely on split here, but if you only have integers and the string is formatted well, you really can use `.split("[^0-9-]+")`. To get rid of the first empty element, use `.replaceFirst("^[^0-9-]+", "")` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
    String[] tokens = twoVectors.split("[^\\d-]+");
```

`[^\\d-]+` : match anything except digits and `-`

`[]`      : match everything mentioned inside `[]`

`^`       : negation mean do not match (`\\d-`)

`\\d-`    : digits `0-9` and `-` character

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/BmB7HR/2)

---

```
    String twoVectors = "a=<-1,2,-3> b=<4,-5,6>";

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String[] tokens = twoVectors.split("[^\\d-]");

    for (String s : tokens)
        if (!s.equals(""))
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

Output :

```
[-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6]
```

Or

you can use `Pattern` along with `matcher` to find all the desired values i.e singed or unsigned numbers with `-?\\d+` regex

[**`Regex Demo -?\d+`**](https://regex101.com/r/BIn9Qz/2)

---

**Update :**  For `Double` values , you can use [`[^\\d-.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/eZnFtE/1) and make sure to use `Double` instead of `Integer` along with `Double.parseDouble`

And with `Pattern` and `Matcher` use [`-?\\d*\\.?\\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/6zGDPg/1)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works but it doesn't work well for decimals like 4.5 or .15. What delimiter would work for that. I've tried multiple delimiters and it treats the decimal as two points. 1.5 will become two separate numbers 1 and 5

Comment: @Frogel4 try the update as i have moved my previously deleted comments to my answer

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much

Comment: @Frogel4 i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The regex that you currently have splits the string on anything *but* digits. So anything that is not a digit is considered a splitter. If you added `-` sign to this pattern, anything that is not a digit or a `-` sign will be included. This will work for some cases, but will fail if you have `-` or `.` without a number afterwards.

What you need to do is to specify the number format in a regex (like `-?\d*.?\d+`), and then find all matches of this pattern. You will also need to change the numbers to `Double` so that you can parse decimal numbers.

```
String twoVectors = "a=<-1,.2,-3> b=<4,-5,6>";

ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("-?\\d*\\.?\\d+").matcher(twoVectors);    
while (matcher.find()) {
   numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group()));
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers.toArray()));
```

Output

`[-1.0, 0.2, -3.0, 4.0, -5.0, 6.0]`

Comment: Thanks. When I use the vector function:                                                   String twoVectors = "a=<-1.9,.2,-3> b=<4,-5.8,6>";                                             The program returns: [-1.0, 0.9, 0.2, -3.0, 4.0, -5.0, 0.8, 6.0]

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^\\d-]` inside your split method i.e. `twoVectors.split("[^\\d-]")`

Why `[^\\d-]`:

> `^`  : Finds regex that must match at the beginning of the line.
>
> `\d` : Any digit from [0-9]
>
> `-`  : will match `'-'` if it exists

Answer (score -1):

A 1-line solution:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays
  .stream(twoVectors.replaceAll("^[^\\d-]+", "").split("[^\\d-]+"))
  .map(Integer::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The initial replace is to remove the leading non-target chars (otherwise the split would return a blank in the first element).